# How to get tag-it working with rails HABTM association?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, tag-it

I have a form where I am using select boxes to be able to pick work locations from a HABTM association:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label "Working Locations", :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <%= f.collection_check_boxes :wrkloc_ids, Wrkloc.all, :id, :wrkstate do |b| %>
          <div class="collection-check-box-altered">
            <%= b.check_box %>
            <%= b.label %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I need to be able to use a text field where I can add multiple tags from the list. I can get some of it to work with:

```
<div class="form-group">  
  <%= f.label :work_locations_test, :class => 'control-label col-lg-2' %>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <%= f.text_field :wrkloc_ids, :class => 'form-control add-tags' %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*tag-it works there, and shows :wrkloc_ids within tags. I need it to show :wrkstate, be able to autocomplete from the :wrklocs list and I need it to pass the whitelist.

associate.rb:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :wrklocs, dependent: :destroy
```

associates_controller.rb whitelist:

```
def associate_params
  params.require(:associate).permit(:name, :wrkstate, { wrkloc_ids:[] })
end
```

schema:

```
  create_table "associates_wrklocs", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "associate_id", null: false
    t.integer "wrkloc_id",    null: false
  end

  create_table "wrklocs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "wrkstate"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

tag-it jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".add-tags").tagit({

            // Options
            fieldName: "wrkloc_ids",
            availableTags: ['AL', 'AK', 'AR', 'AZ', 'CA', 'CO', 'CT', 'DE', 'FL', 'GA', 'HI', 'ID', 'IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'KY', 'LA', 'ME', 'MD', 'MA', 'MI', 'MN', 'MS', 'MO', 'MT', 'NE', 'NV', 'NH', 'NJ', 'NM', 'NY', 'NC', 'ND', 'OH', 'OK', 'OR', 'PA', 'RI', 'SC', 'SD', 'TN', 'TX', 'UT', 'VT', 'VA', 'WA', 'WV', 'WI', 'WY'],
            //autocomplete: {delay: 0, minLength: 2},
            //showAutocompleteOnFocus: false,
            removeConfirmation: false,
            caseSensitive: true,
            allowDuplicates: false,
            allowSpaces: false,
            readOnly: false,
            tagLimit: null,
            singleField: false,
            singleFieldDelimiter: ' ',
            singleFieldNode: null,
            tabIndex: null,
            placeholderText: "type state abbreviation",

            // Events
            onTagClicked: function(event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.tag);
                console.log(ui.tagLabel);
                //window.location = ui.tag;
                //window.open(ui.tagLabel);
            },
            onTagLimitExceeded: function(event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.tag);
            }

        });

    });
  </script>
```

*Plus there I am grabbing availableTags: from a list I wrote. I need it to pull from like Wrkloc.all maybe?